# I have two dataframes I want to compare without changing the order of the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of similar shape that look like this:

```
df1:
             ID       Qty   Price      Expiry
Date                                         
2016-01-05  id1  0.000294  2950.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-05  id2  0.000254  2850.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-06  id1  0.000394  3950.0  2016-02-14
2016-01-06  id3  0.000594  3850.0  2016-02-15

df2
             ID       Qty   Price      Expiry
Date                                         
2016-01-05  id2  0.000294  2950.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-05  id1  0.000254  2850.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-06  id1  0.000394  3950.0  2016-02-14
2016-01-06  id2  0.000594  3850.0  2016-02-15
```

I wish to create a third df that retains the same order of dates but compares the *'Qty'*, *'Price'* and *'Expiry'* for each given *'ID'* in the following manner:

```
             ID       Qty_diff    Price_diff     Expiry_match
Date                                         
2016-01-05  id2      0.000294     2950.0         2016-03-18
2016-01-05  id1      0.000254     2850.0         2016-03-18
2016-01-06  id1      0.000394     3950.0         2016-02-14
2016-01-06  id2      0.000594     3850.0         2016-02-15
```

I've tried doing a difference between the dataframes but due to mismatch in id orders the results aren't reliable.

To recreate the dfs:

```py
import pandas as pd 


data1 = [['2016-01-05', 'id1', 0.000294, 2950.0, '2016-03-18'],
       ['2016-01-05', 'id2', 0.000254, 2850.0, '2016-03-18'],
       ['2016-01-06', 'id1', 0.000394, 3950.0, '2016-02-14'],
       ['2016-01-06', 'id3', 0.000594, 3850.0, '2016-02-15']]
data2 = [['2016-01-05', 'id2', 0.000294, 2950.0, '2016-03-18'],
       ['2016-01-05', 'id1', 0.000254, 2850.0, '2016-03-18'],
       ['2016-01-06', 'id1', 0.000394, 3950.0, '2016-02-14'],
       ['2016-01-06', 'id2', 0.000594, 3850.0, '2016-02-15']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=cols)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=cols)

df1
Out[7]: 
         Date   ID       Qty   Price      Expiry
0  2016-01-05  id1  0.000294  2950.0  2016-03-18
1  2016-01-05  id2  0.000254  2850.0  2016-03-18
2  2016-01-06  id1  0.000394  3950.0  2016-02-14
3  2016-01-06  id3  0.000594  3850.0  2016-02-15

df1.set_index('Date')
Out[8]: 
             ID       Qty   Price      Expiry
Date                                         
2016-01-05  id1  0.000294  2950.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-05  id2  0.000254  2850.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-06  id1  0.000394  3950.0  2016-02-14
2016-01-06  id3  0.000594  3850.0  2016-02-15

df2.set_index('Date')
Out[9]: 
             ID       Qty   Price      Expiry
Date                                         
2016-01-05  id2  0.000294  2950.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-05  id1  0.000254  2850.0  2016-03-18
2016-01-06  id1  0.000394  3950.0  2016-02-14
2016-01-06  id2  0.000594  3850.0  2016-02-15
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be better if you explain what kind of comparison you would like to do. But in any case, you can do groupby based on date and ID and then perform some operations like difference, summation or so on on the other columns

Comment: Just a plain difference comparison. But groupby sounds good. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you properly set up index, then Pandas would automatically align the index when doing the difference,  see code below,

```
df1['Expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Expiry'])
df2['Expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Expiry'])


df1.set_index(['Date','ID']) - df2.set_index(['Date','ID'])
```